# How to send only selected parameters using FormUrlEncoded - Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit library for Api calls.In one of my api's I have to send only selected data.In my function I have 4 parameters but I want to send only selected parameters.

I am using that function

```
@POST(FILTER)
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<JsonObject> filterUsers(@Field("age") String age,
                             @Field("gender") String gender,
                             @Field("height") String height,
                             @Field("weight") String weight);
```

I want that only selected parameter should be added to that function.
In that function it can be any of these parameter or some combination of these parameters
How can I do that?

**For example** if I have the value of age and gender than I have to call api from only these two values or if I have the value of height and age then I have to call the api from only height and age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `FieldMap` like below:

```
@POST(FILTER)
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<JsonObject> filterUsers(@FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);
```

Then, pass `map` with desired fields only.

Comment: Ok let me give it a try